Question about Security proof of Gentry's Anonymous IBE
In Gentry's paper "Practical Identity-Based Encryption without Random Oracles", I have a little difficulty understanding the security proof part.
The paper claims that in the Challenge phase: "$\mathsf{ID}$ must not have appeared in any key generation query in Phase 1" while in Phase 2: "the adversary may not request a private key for $\mathsf{ID}$ or the decryption of $(\mathsf{ID}, C)$"
But in the security proof part, these 2 restrictions seem to be omitted. Can anyone explain why?

The restrictions are omitted on purpose because, without loss of generality, we can assume that the adversary $\mathcal{A}$ does not make such queries. To elaborate, we can always transform $\mathcal{A}$ to an adversary $\mathcal{A}^*$ that has the same winning probability as $\mathcal{A}$ and does not make any of the prohibited queries. $\mathcal{A}^*$ works as follows in the ANON-IND-ID-CCA game.
Setup: On receiving $params$ from the challenger, $\mathcal{A}^*$ invokes $\mathcal{A}$ with $params$.
Phase 1: On receving any query from $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A}^*$ forwards it to its challenger. The response from the challenger is sent to $\mathcal{A}$.
Challenge: $\mathcal{A}^*$ receives $M_0, M_1, ID_0, ID_1$ from $\mathcal{A}$. If $ID_0$ or $ID_1$ was queried in Phase 1, $\mathcal{A}^*$ aborts the game. Otherwise, it forwards $M_0, M_1, ID_0, ID_1$ to the challenger. It receives the challenge ciphertext $C$ and sends it to $\mathcal{A}$.
Phase 2: On receiving a key generation query $ID$ from $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A}^*$ checks whether $ID \in \{ID_0, ID_1\}$. If yes, it responds with $\bot$ (or does whatever the challenger would have done, i.e., either sends back some other message or aborts the game). Otherwise, it follows the steps in the Phase 1. Similarly, if $\mathcal{A}$ queries the decryption oracle on $(ID_0, C)$ or $(ID_1, C)$, $\mathcal{A}^*$ would respond with $\bot$ (or does whatever the challenger would have done). Otherwise, it follows the steps in the Phase 1.
Guess: $\mathcal{A}^*$ will receive $b', c' \in \{0,1\}$ from $\mathcal{A}$. It forwards these to the challenger.
Surprisingly in the proof, which assumes an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that wins the ANON-IND-ID-CCA game with a significant advantage, the reduction $\mathcal{B}$ does generate the secret key for $ID_b$. But observe that this key is never given to the adversary $\mathcal{A}$ but is used to generate the challenger ciphertext. Essentially, if $Z = e(g_{q+1}, g'\;)$, then $\mathcal{B}$ has simulated the ANON-IND-ID-CCA game with a valid ciphertext whereas, if $Z$ was truly random, it has simulated the game but the challenge ciphertext does not reveal any information regarding $b, c$. In other words, if $Z = e(g_{q+1}, g'\;)$, $\mathcal{A}$ can guess $b, c$ with significant advantage whereas, if $Z$ was random, it would guess with negligible advantage. Using this difference, $\mathcal{B}$ can break the truncated decision ABDHE assumption.
